# 'adding' a heading to the nth column of a set of colums

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, data, grid-layouts, headers-footers

Suppose there are nth columns in my TableForm of data.
Mathematica enables users to label their header.
However, is there a way to add header **only** the nth column?
What about adding headings to a set of columns **between** the $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ column?

Comment: You could just use an empty string (`""`) for each of the columns where you don't want a heading.

Comment: Is there a fast way to do this? That's what I'm looking for. If there are 1000 Columns that I wanted to have a "" heading, I cannot possibly do this for each one...@march

Comment: `headings=ReplacePart[ConstantArray["", 1000], 950 -> "Your Title"]` Creates an array of 1000 empty strings then replaces the 950th with a title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
makeHeadings[{imax_Integer, jmax_Integer}, headings, len_Integer] := 
   Join[Table["", {imax - 1}], headings, Table["", {len - jmax}]]
```

Usage:

```
makeHeadings[{3, 5}, {"a", "b", "c"}, 8]
{"", "", "a", "b", "c", "", "", ""}
```

Then,

```
TableForm[Array[a, {3, 8}], TableHeadings -> {None, makeHeadings[{3, 5}, {"a", "b", "c"}, 8]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the grid?

```
Grid[{{Text["Cln2"], SpanFromLeft}, {a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}, Spacings -> {2, 2}]
```

or as @march suggested:

```
TableForm[{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}, TableHeadings -> {None, {"", "Cln2", ""}}]
(*But there is a line above the table*)
```

Comment: Is there a fast way to do this? That's what I'm looking for. If there are 1000 Columns that I wanted to have a "" heading, I cannot possibly do this for each one..